# Create an Excel/CSV list based on a varying HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv, plc

Looking for a way to do the next:

1. Load data to my HTML table
2. Export it to Excel
3. Change the data after 1 second
4. Export to Excel at next row
5. Load new data...

This table is being generated by my PLC with its webServer functionality and I don't think there is a chance to install many features, so I have to rely on native functionalities of the languages/browsers.

The table looks like this (I want to update this structure by the way):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
    <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <META name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Temperature data</title>
</head>
<body>
        
    <p class='title'>Temperature data</p>
    
    <form action='index.htm' method='get' id='form1' name='form1' onsubmit='return false'>
    <div class='pagebody'>

        <p class='sectiontitle'></p>
        <table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Um</th>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8960</td>
                <td>S_Temp1</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08960',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8963</td>
                <td>S_New1</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08963',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8964</td>
                <td>S_New2</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08964',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8965</td>
                <td>S_New3</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08965',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8961</td>
                <td>S_Other1</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08961',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>8962</td>
                <td>S_Other2</td>
                <td><script type='text/javascript'>/*EVO_Text*/(true,'t08962',10,10,1,1,'')</script></td>
                <td>&deg;C</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

"Value" is imported from my PLC memory with a Javascript function called EVO_Text. Ultimately, it shows whatever value I read from my CPU. "txxxxx" is just the memory address of the specific variable at the CPU, don't mind it.

**EDIT:** I was trying to find a structure for this problem and I believe this could be made by storing the data in a very big sized array and later exporting it by clicking on a "download" button, but I have yet to find some advice regarding the ".csv" file.

I need this function to be loaded every time the HTML table shows the new data in order to end up making a linear graph. I require this to make myself a little SCADA to read the quality of my multiple sensors.

I am not a web designer, but an industrial programmer...